# Why is it invalid syntax to call an Action member in this way?

Tags: c#

The following code produces a syntax error:

```
class Foo
{
    public Action a = () => { };
}

void doSomething() 
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    (foo.a)(); // error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
}
```

However, the following alternatives both work:

```
foo.a();                // works
Action a = foo.a; a();  // works
```

Why is this so? `(foo.a)` is an `Action`; why can't I call it?

Comment: Why would you *want* to call it that way?

Comment: I would guess for the same reason you cannot do `(Console.WriteLine)("Hello");`, or `(a)();` in your second example.

Comment: @Will I don't have a specific reason to call it that way; I'm just interested in why it's invalid.

Comment: Voting to close as the answer is "because that's not the right syntax".

Comment: Me too then. It's a silly question :).

Comment: "paging messrs skeet and lippert"

Comment: But you can write `((Console.WriteLine))("");`

Comment: @Robert Moskal: It's only a silly question if you're not interested in the intricacies of the language. You'll find a *lot* of answers citing the C# language spec here and the vast majority of them are informative... but only to those who care.

Comment: Note that `foo.a()` is shorthand for `foo.a.Invoke()`, so you can write `(foo.a).Invoke()`. There's a related issue with the C# 6 null-propagation operator: you can't write `foo.a?()` but you can write `foo.a?.Invoke()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### What does happen?

That is because the piece of code `(foo.a)();` would evaluate to a *cast-expression*, as `foo.a` could be either a *member-access* or a *type*.
And that's why the compiler is searching for an expression inside the empty brackets.

For example consider the following snippet:

```
Func<string, int> fn = null;
int x = (fn)("asd"); // The type or namespace "fn" could not be found
```

Here the compiler clearly states that it interpreted it as a *cast-expression*, as it expects `fn` to be a *type*.

So, inside the first set of brackets nothing can be that could be read as a *type*, because that will cause the whole expression to be read as a *cast-expression*.

The following snippet compiles:

```
(new Action<int>(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); }))(1);
(new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("asd1"); }))();
((Console.WriteLine))("asd2");
((Action)null)();

Action a = null; 
(true ? a : null)();
((a))();
```

But these lines do not:

```
(Console.WriteLine)("asd");
Action a = null;
(a)();
Action<string> b = null;
(b)("");
```

### Why does it happen?

It turns out that the *syntactic grammar* is ambiguous. Why does the parser interpret `(a)()` as a *cast-expression*, when it is not, but it could interpret it as an *invocation-expression*? When does the parser decide if it is going to be a *cast* or an *invocation*? Well, they thought of this. The specification says (§7.7.6):

> The grammar for a cast-expression leads to certain syntactic ambiguities. For example, the expression (x)–y
>   could either be interpreted as a cast-expression (a cast of –y to type x) or as an additive-expression combined
>   with a parenthesized-expression (which computes the value x – y).
>
> To resolve cast-expression ambiguities, the following rule exists: A sequence of one or more tokens (§2.3.3)
>   enclosed in parentheses is considered the start of a cast-expression only if at least one of the following are true:
>
> - The sequence of tokens is correct grammar for a type, but not for an expression.
> - The sequence of tokens is correct grammar for a type, and the token immediately following the closing
>     parentheses is the token “~”, the token “!”, the token “(”, an identifier (§2.4.1), a literal (§2.4.4), or any
>     keyword (§2.4.3) except as and is.

In this case, *"The sequence of tokens is correct grammar for a type, and the token immediately following the closing parentheses is the token `(`"* stands, so this is the end of the story.

### Syntactic grammar

From the [C# 5.0 Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

```
cast-expression:
  ( type ) unary-expression

unary-expression:
  primary-expression
  ...
  cast-expression
  await-expression

expression:
  non-assignment-expression
  assignment

non-assignment-expression:
  conditional-expression
  lambda-expression
  query-expression

// conditional expression at the end can contain a single unary-expression

invocation-expression:
  primary-expression ( argument-list_opt )

primary-expression:
  primary-no-array-creation-expression
  array-creation-expression

primary-no-array-creation-expression:
  literal
  simple-name
  parenthesized-expression
  ...

parenthesized-expression:
  ( expression )

expression-statement:
  statement-expression ;

statement-expression:
  invocation-expression
  object-creation-expression
  assignment
  post-increment-expression
  post-decrement-expression
  pre-increment-expression
  pre-decrement-expression
  await-expression
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `(foo.a)()`, syntactically you are taking the `()` out of the 'scope'/context of `(foo.a)`

Meaning, you are calling `foo.a`, which is syntactically invalid, then calling `()` on the result of that operation.

In other words, asking for `()` on the **result** of the expression `(foo.a)`, rather than requesting `a()` of `foo`.

*Edit: See comments*

Comment: `foo.a` is perfectly syntactically valid. In fact, accessing `foo.a` first *is* the way that `foo.a()` is evaluated.

Comment: `(foo.a)` definitely does not call `a`.

Comment: Conceptually sure, but calling `foo.a;`, as a statement in code, is definitely not valid.

Comment: As a statement, but as an expression it's fine: `var b = foo.a;`

Comment: Keep in mind here that `a` is not a method. It's a field containing a delegate.

Comment: No, good point there. Doing it explicitly through assignments as `var b = foo.a; b()` would be valid - so does again raise the question why piping directly as (foo.a)() shouldn't be...